# From JSON object to Tableview

Tags: javascript, json, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I've been messing around with this for a while now, but I can't seem to get it done.

I get tasks as JSON-data back from my API. The data looks like this, printed with `Ti.API.info(this.responseText)`:

```
[INFO] [{"created_at":"2012-01-09T15:05:25Z","description":"Smullen van onze pizza","id":1,"title":"Pizza Eten","updated_at":"2012-01-09T15:05:25Z","user_id":11},{"created_at":"2012-01-09T15:05:25Z","description":"Lekker Lekker!","id":21,"title":"Ice-Tea Drinken","updated_at":"2012-01-09T15:05:25Z","user_id":11}]
```

I'm not quite sure how to process this data. I tried a couple of things:

```
getData.onload = function(){
    var tasks = this.responseText;
    for(t in tasks) {
        Ti.API.info(t);
    }
        }
```

This printed:

```
[INFO] 0
[INFO] 1
[INFO] 2
[INFO] 3
[INFO] 4
[INFO] 5
[INFO] 6
```

till 306.

Another thing I tried was:

```
var tasks = this.responseText;
for(t in tasks)
{
    if(tasks.hasOwnProperty(t))
    {
        Ti.API.info(t + " -> " + tasks[t]);
    }
}
```

This gave me:

```
[INFO] 0 -> [
[INFO] 1 -> {
[INFO] 2 -> "
[INFO] 3 -> c
[INFO] 4 -> r
[INFO] 5 -> e
[INFO] 6 -> a
[INFO] 7 -> t
[INFO] 8 -> e
[INFO] 9 -> d
```

Another try:

```
var tasks = this.responseText;
for(t in tasks)
{
    Ti.API.info(t.title);
}
```

Gave:

```
[INFO] <null>
[INFO] <null>
[INFO] <null>
```

I'm really confused how to process this JSON and how to 'prepare' it so i can use it in a tableview. Anyone can help me out here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as skypanther already pointed out. you need to parse your json string to an object. it's well explained at [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html). after you parsed your string into an object it is easy to access its members and create your tableview row.

```
/* create the tableview row */
makeTableViewRow = function(_object){

  var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
     ...
  }]

  var title = Ti.UI.createLabel({
     ...
     text: _object.title,
     ...
  });
  row.add(title);

  return row;
};


getData.onload = function(){
  var tasks = json.parse(this.responseText), /* parse the json string */
      _rowsForTableView = []; /* put the rows in here */

  /* create the rows */
  for (i in tasks){
     var _row = makeTableView(tasks[i]);
     _rowsForTableView.push(_row);
  };

  myTableView.setData(_rowsForTableView);

};
```

Answer (score 1):

responseText is giving you a string. You want it to be an object to either loop through it as you're trying or to put it in a table. Try JSON.parse(this.responseText) to get that object.

The table.data property expects an array of objects, with properties that line up with those of the Ti.UI.TableViewRow object. I haven't tried putting your code into a project. But it looks like your JSON data, if converted to an object, will line up just fine.

In other words, table.data = JSON.parse(this.responseText) should work. Variables might not be in scope, so you might need to do more than just drop that line into your onload callback.

Comment: If I put the JSON.parse line and then do: for(t in tasks)
   {
    Ti.API.info(t.title);
   }, I still get <null> twice. Any idea about that? Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: In your statement, "t" is the index in to the tasks array. It's not the object itself. tasks[t].title will yield the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Once you convert the string to the object (via JSON.parse) it may help to get a visual representation of that object - you can do that with my dp_debug component here:

http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_debug/

It's not to solve your problem directly, but it will show exactly what that object "looks" like.

It's old (ancient in JS terms) but I still find it insanely useful for this kind of thing.  Hope it helps.